# create subscription for a shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I would like to create a subscription for incoming mails on a shared mailbox with Microsoft graph.

Background:

- I have an app created with delegated user rights:

  Read all webhook subscriptions (preview)

  Read and write user mailbox settings

  Read and write user and shared mail
- I have created a shared mail box
- I have added a user to that shared mailbox.
- I have added the shared mailbox to the users folders so I see users mailbox and the shared mailbox in the WEB GUI

I have created a c# program to receive auth token, created subscriptions and listed messages from a mailbox

What works:

- Receiving auth token
- List messages of users mail box
- List messages of shared mailbox
- Create subscription on users mail box

It does not work if I try to create a subscription for incoming mails
 in the shared mail box.

My resource string during creation of the subscription is:

`Resource = users/xx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages`

As said works well with the users mail address but fails using the shared mail box address:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxxx-8515-4048-8c05-f3eb91a1f69a",
      "date": "2018-12-13T15:17:09"
    }
  }
}Subscription failed because:Forbidden
```

Did I use the wrong resource string here or did I miss an app right here?

Comment: according to 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/new-email-notification-for-shared-mailboxes/356cca22-6b23-440c-84a4-3a7b1c4021ad

this will never work
This is 'expected behavior' for shared mailboxes- you'd need to add it as an account, not a shared mailbox, to get notifications. You could use macros to watch the inbox and alert you when a new message arrived.

Answer (score -1):

according to 
[Microsoft comunity][1]https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/new-email-notification-for-shared-mailboxes/356cca22-6b23-440c-84a4-3a7b1c4021ad

this will never work
This is 'expected behavior' for shared mailboxes- you'd need to add it as an account, not a shared mailbox, to get notifications. You could use macros to watch the inbox and alert you when a new message arrived.